# Extracting matrices from tensors

Tags: python, matrix, rgb, tensor

So I am trying to write a function that converts RGB to HSI on Python.

I have an image that is saved in np.ndarray (tensor I suppose?) with dimensions (1080, 1920, 3), that is - 1080x1920 pixels in RGB. How can I extract matrix of R/G/B; after I get H/S/I, how do I concatenate the matrices to get back the tensor (1080, 1920, 3)?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming `your_image` contains the RGB channels, you can extract each channel using the corresponding index:

```py
r = your_image[..., 0]
g = your_image[..., 1]
b = your_image[..., 2]
```

*Note:* You may need to normalize the values to the interval [0.0, 1.0]. If so, divide them by 255.0.

Conversely, you can stack the three channels together as follows:

```py
import numpy as np
your_image = np.dstack((r, g, b))
```